# gulp-imagemin: error "pPipe(...) is not a function"

Tags: gulp, gulp-imagemin

Running `gulp-imagemin` causes the following error:

```
/.../node_modules/imagemin/index.js:64
const pipe = opts.plugins.length > 0 ? pPipe(opts.plugins)(input) : Promise.resolve(input);
                                                          ^

TypeError: pPipe(...) is not a function
```

Source:

```
import plugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';
...
gulp.task('img:production', () =>
  gulp.src(`${config.dirs.src}/img/**/*`)
  .pipe(plugins().imagemin())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(`${config.dirs.dist}/img`))
);
...
gulp.task('build:production',
  [
   'img:production',
   'html:production',
   'css:production',
   'js:production',
   'copy',
   'critical',
  ],
);
```

- Gulp: `3.9.1`
- Gulp-Imagemin: `3.2.0`

Comment: Running into the same problem.

Comment: mchange mm hi ..can you  (just for test )  change your src .. with a 'source/of/one/img.jpg ? .. without string interpolation (ES6) and with a secure image?

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi thanks for your comment. But I already raised an issue after Doug's comment and got an answer, that it is a known issue, which should be fixed with the upcomming version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with the current version of `gulp-imagemin`. But it should be **fixed with the upcomming version**, according to that issue: https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-imagemin/issues/261